# Check if any items in a list of string is not located in a list of objects

Tags: c#, list

Say I have this list of strings that I'm using to create a list of objects.

My list of strings has a count of 171 items in it, while my list of objects has 170. So one did not passed, but I need to figure out which one.

Luckily, all the strings can be found in each name of each object. That means that, for example:

```
string nameObjOne
```

Will equals to this:

```
public class myObj
{
    public string myName {get;set;}
}
```

So how can I check if all the strings in my first list are located in the list of objects so that I may figure out which one is not there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select items that are in `List<string>` but does not have corresponding item in `List<myObj>` using LINQ:

```
var results = strings.Except(myObjects.Select(o => o.myName)).ToArray();
```

After that, you can just check length of `results` array to determine, if there is such an item.

It is *O(n+m)* solution, because of `Except` implementation, which uses `HastSet`.

Comment: Also note OPs want objects also, not just `strings`

Comment: Well, this worked perfectly and gave me the item I wanted. Bad item! Thank you.

Comment: Any reference showing that `Except` uses a `Hashset`? That'd be great

Comment: @caerolus I believe the real implementation is very similar to the one described by Jon Skeet in his eduLINQ series: [Part 17 - Except](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-17-except.aspx). It's just the easiest, and the most logic solution.

Comment: @caerolus: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx) states that the return value is the _set difference_.  This means that duplicates will be not be considered important -- `{1, 1, 2}` is equivalent to `{1, 2}`.

Comment: @AustinSalonen so? what does that have to do with internally using a `HashSet` or not?